# Word conversion from pages is corrupted

Tags: pages

I'm converting a pages document to word. I've tried the export and save as .doc method. Both files  appear identical but when I try and open either with word, it says the file is corrupted and it cannot open. I tried the option of open and repair, but still no luck. Any suggestions on how to get it to work? I need to have someone edit the pages document in word because they only have access to word.

Comment: Which versions of Pages and Word are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Something you could try is installing [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org) and opening the Word formatted document there and immediately resaving it. I've found that LibreOffice is much more forgiving and saving a document through it will result in a file that Word will be able to open without issue. Same with Excel formatted spreadsheets that refuse to open in Excel.

I usually end up installing LibreOffice on every machine I use specifically for this reason.